# Optimal use of LIKE on indexed column

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I have a large table (+- 1 million rows, 7 columns including the primary key). The table contains two columns (ie: `symbol_01` and `symbol_02`) that are indexed and used for querying. This table contains rows such as:

```
id    symbol_01    symbol_02   value_01  value_02
1     aaa          bbb         12        15
2     bbb          aaa         12        15
3     ccc          ddd         20        50
4     ddd          ccc         20        50
```

As per the example rows 1 and 2 are identical except that `symbol_01` and `symbol_02` are swapped but they have the same values for `value_01` and `value_02`. That is true once again with row 3 and 4. This is the case for the entire table, there are essentially two rows for each combination of `symbol_01`+`symbol_02`.

I need to figure out a better way of handling this to get rid of the duplication. So far the solution I am considering is to just have one column called `symbol` which would be a combination of the two symbols, so the table would be as follows:

```
id    symbol       value_01   value_02
1     ,aaa,bbb,    12         15
2     ,ccc,ddd,    20         50
```

This would cut the number of rows in half. As a side note, every value in the `symbol` column will be unique. Results always need to be queried for using both symbols, so I would do:

```
select value_01, value_02
from my_table
where symbol like '%,aaa,%' and symbol like '%,bbb,%'
```

This would work but my question is around performance. This is still going to be a big table (and will get bigger soon). So my question is, is this the best solution for this scenario given that `symbol` will be indexed, every `symbol` combination will be unique, and I will need to use `LIKE` to query results.

Is there a better way to do this? Im not sure how great `LIKE` is for performance but I don't see an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this index:

```
create index symbol_index on t (
    least(symbol_01, symbol_02),
    greatest(symbol_01, symbol_02)
)
```

The query would be:

```
select *
from t
where 
    least(symbol_01, symbol_02) = least('aaa', 'bbb')
    and
    greatest(symbol_01, symbol_02) = greatest('aaa', 'bbb')
```

Or simply delete the duplicates:

```
delete from t
using (
    select distinct on (
        greatest(symbol_01, symbol_02),
        least(symbol_01, symbol_02),
        value_01, value_02
    ) id
    from t
    order by
        greatest(symbol_01, symbol_02),
        least(symbol_01, symbol_02),
        value_01, value_02
) s
where id = s.id
```

Depending on the columns semantics it might be better to normalize the table as suggested by [@Bohemian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38883308/131874)

Answer (score 2):

There's no high performance solution, because your problem is shoehorning multiple values into one column.

Create a child table (with a foreign key to your current/main table) to *separately* hold all the individual values you want to search on, index that column and your query will be simple *and* fast.